# Why getline is reading my entire unicode file

Tags: c++, string, unicode, getline

I have seen many threads but none of solution given is working for me, so if anyone can throw some light that would be great
I am reading unicode file and using getline i try to scan line by line but then it scans the entire file, since the objects are wstring it does not allow me to place delimeter in getline. and asks only wchar_t in which i cant fit the delimeter. (\0 does not work as i am reading in binary mode) so below is code snippet
Platform: Windows , Visual Studio 2010
Unicode encoding: UTF 16

```
wifstream fin("profiles1.prd", ios_base::binary);  //open a file
wofstream fout("DXout.txt",ios_base::binary);  // this dumps the parsing ouput
fin.imbue(std::locale(fin.getloc(),new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::consume_header>));
fout.imbue(std::locale(fin.getloc(),new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::consume_header>));
wstring stream;
getline(fin,stream);
```

Comment: The file do contain newlines? In the correct format?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes file has multiple lines, and what is correct format do you mean? i have simple unicode text file with mutiple lines in it.

Comment: By "correct format" I mean are you sure the newlines is UTF-16 format and not just plain single-byte `'\n'`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes the input file is encoded in UTF 16 format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am hopeful this is what you're looking for:

```
fin.imbue(std::locale(fin.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff,
        std::codecvt_mode(std::little_endian|std::consume_header)>);
```

Windows is little-endian, and as such to both skip the BOM *and* imbue utf16, you need to punch it in the gut by inventing a new conversion mode.

Hope it helps you out. I leave the *writing* side to you.